# Assembly puzzle - binary bomb

Tags: assembly, gdb

I have the following assembly code:

```
0x08048d36 <+0>:     push   %ebp
0x08048d37 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048d39 <+3>:     push   %esi
0x08048d3a <+4>:     push   %ebx
0x08048d3b <+5>:     sub    $0x20,%esp
0x08048d3e <+8>:     lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
0x08048d41 <+11>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
0x08048d45 <+15>:    lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048d48 <+18>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
0x08048d4c <+22>:    movl   $0x804a28a,0x4(%esp)
0x08048d54 <+30>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048d57 <+33>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048d5a <+36>:    call   0x8048758 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
0x08048d5f <+41>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
0x08048d62 <+44>:    jg     0x8048d69 <phase_5+51>
0x08048d64 <+46>:    call   0x80491a8 <explode_bomb>
0x08048d69 <+51>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048d6c <+54>:    and    $0xf,%eax
0x08048d6f <+57>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048d72 <+60>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
0x08048d75 <+63>:    je     0x8048da0 <phase_5+106>
0x08048d77 <+65>:    mov    $0x0,%ecx
0x08048d7c <+70>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
0x08048d81 <+75>:    mov    $0x804a1e0,%ebx
0x08048d86 <+80>:    add    $0x1,%edx
0x08048d89 <+83>:    mov    (%ebx,%eax,4),%eax
0x08048d8c <+86>:    add    %eax,%ecx
0x08048d8e <+88>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
0x08048d91 <+91>:    jne    0x8048d86 <phase_5+80>
0x08048d93 <+93>:    mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048d96 <+96>:    cmp    $0xf,%edx
0x08048d99 <+99>:    jne    0x8048da0 <phase_5+106>
0x08048d9b <+101>:   cmp    -0x10(%ebp),%ecx
0x08048d9e <+104>:   je     0x8048da5 <phase_5+111>
0x08048da0 <+106>:   call   0x80491a8 <explode_bomb>
0x08048da5 <+111>:   add    $0x20,%esp
0x08048da8 <+114>:   pop    %ebx
0x08048da9 <+115>:   pop    %esi
0x08048daa <+116>:   pop    %ebp
0x08048dab <+117>:   ret
```

Scanf expects two numbers from the user. The address $0x804a1e0, referenced in line <+75>, seems to reference an array. When I grab the values of that array, I get:

```
(gdb) x/15dw 0x804a1e0
0x804a1e0 <array.2985>: 10      2       14      7
0x804a1f0 <array.2985+16>:      8       12      15      11
0x804a200 <array.2985+32>:      0       4       1       13
0x804a210 <array.2985+48>:      3       9       6
```

I have no idea what I'm supposed to do with this information though. I know that there is a loop within this assembly code, that keeps going back to line <+80> until $eax holds the value 15, but I'm lost as to what code this function requires to successfully exit.

Comment: You want the gdb command `x /15dw 0x804a1e0` to display the contents of the array (words, not bytes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code looks like it's basically

```
static int array[15] = { 10, 2, 14, 7, 8, 12, 15, 11, 0, 4, 1, 13, 3, 9, 6 };
void phase_5(char *s) {
    int a, b;
    if (sscanf(s, "%d%d", &a, &b) <= 1)
        explode_bomb();
    a &= 0xf;
    if (a != 0xf) {
        int c = 0, d = 0;
        do {
            d++;
            a = array[a];
            c += a;
        } while (a != 0xf);
        if (d == 15 && c == b) return;
    }
    explode_bomb();
}
```

Comment: @ChrisDodd  I'm sorry I'm new to C , can you explain more , how do you actually get value of %d %d from the above ? is  it ( 15, 115 ) ? I'm trying to follow this but still don't get it.  a=15 , b= sum( array[i] ) ?

Comment: @JPC: `"%d%d"` is the string at address 0x804a28a, and is assumed from the statement "Scanf expects two numbers from the user", since the contents of that memory isn't actually shown.

Comment: @JPC -- the "solution" (input that doesn't trigger the bomb) is the initial value for a that results in looping through the entire array (which is the only number in 0..15 NOT present in the array), and b = sum(array).  So 5 115 is the key

Comment: hi @ChrisDodd,  so I 'm trying to figure it out from the code. above. how could I get return without explode the bomb. from reading this.. I am new to C and trying to read this code. but didn't quite get it ,  so  there 's looping 15 times, adding up c , thus c should be my input b , correct ? but "a" must not equal to 0xf , which is 14 , so is that mean  array[14] , exclude from the sum all  ? 115 is sum all, 115 - 6 ?  => so input to avoid bomb would be 15,109 or %d,%d